# Get list of orders that have not been closed that are older than 60 days

Tags: mysql, php

I have a table `te_dates` that holds order status information for orders.

The table is a many-to-one relationship, so one order can have many row inserts into my `order_status` table.

*(`dsc_id` is the order status code)*

```
order_id | dsc_id |             te_date | te_date_id
----------------------------------------------------
    2880 |      1 | 2014-11-19 09:27:18 |      16486
    2880 |      2 | 2014-11-19 09:27:23 |      16487
    2880 |      3 | 2014-11-24 14:10:40 |      16710
    2880 |      4 | 2014-11-24 14:10:41 |      16711
    2880 |      0 | 2014-11-24 14:10:49 |      16712
    2880 |      8 | 2014-12-17 15:52:29 |      17782
```

My client is asking me to find all orders that are 60 days or older that have NOT been closed, and change their status.

My thought process is to `select distinct order_id` of files that have been opened (`dsc_id = 1`) that are greater than 60 days old, and are not currently closed (`dsc_id = 8`).

I just can't wrap my head around the query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    o1.order_id
FROM tblOrders o1
WHERE 
    o1.dsc_id = 1
    AND o1.te_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -60 DAY)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT order_id FROM tblOrders o2 WHERE o2.order_id = o1.order_id and o2.dsc_id = 8)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT order_id FROM tblOrders o2 WHERE o2.order_id = o1.order_id and o2.dsc_id != 1)
GROUP BY o1.order_id
```